# Copy full CSS selector in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css-selectors, microsoft-edge

I'm looking for the possibility to copy the full CSS selector of an HTML element in the MS Edge F12 Developer Tools. Is there such a thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "full CSS selector"? Can you give us the scenario and an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: Sure, sorry. I'm using this feature a lot to edit the CSS of WordPress Themes. I make a right click on the HTML element which I want to style (Chrome Browser) > Inspect > copying the selector to address this element. Most often this selector is to restricted. But I'm able to create my own selector out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Edge does not have the option of copying a unique selector path in their developer tools. Chrome and Firefox both do. Edge's styles pane does sort the applied selectors in order or specificity, so you can copy the most specific rule and work from that.

I will, however, caution you about using either technique too heavily. Because it provides a unique selector, you can use it to target a single item. As you pointed out, this is often too restrictive. It's great for an occasional fix to a specific element that is troublesome, but is not the best practice for general development.

A good understanding of [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) helps avoid this, but starting from such a unique selector seems to end with a selector that is needlessly specific. I did a consulting gig a number of years ago where I deleted 50,000 lines of redundant CSS because the designer used this method. We were able to replace this code with a scant 550 lines. It took them nearly 5 years to get to that point, but they had actually exceeded the maximum number of selectors IE could support at the time.

Comment: Thanks @LightBender Good to know that Edge doesn't have it. An yes I do support your opinion about selectors!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge 85 does:

1. Inspect Element
2. Right click on the element
3. On the copy contextual menu select "Copy selector"[image]